# How to implement a radius search using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, query, search

I am very new to this topic and after a long time of research I didn't find a solution.
I want a query that I can use on my PostGIS database performing a radiussearch.. I inserted the Open Street Map Data from Geofarbik covering whole Austria.
The Input parameters are a point in lng,lat notation, like Point(16 48) ~ some point in Vienna and as second parameter the radius in m.

For a reason I don't know the lat lon values in the db are somewhat different. On the internet I found people talking about different types of SRID, but I really don't know which SRID I should use and how it could be useful to me to compare the input data with the data in the database.
I added a column geom, because the command ST_Within(geom, geom) needs a geom. Now the data is even less readable, so I cleary don't know what to do with the input data for comparing and knowing it was done the right way.
I can't look behind the concept of the SRID in this moment.

```
SELECT * mytable node
WHERE node.tags @> ARRAY['subway', 'station', 'uic_ref']
and ST_DWithin(geom, st_makepoint(mylon, mylat), radius) = true
```

My query would look like this, but I doesn't work yet. 
If someone could give me some advices how to speed up queries like this it would be great to.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please **[edit]** the new information (added as a comment to an answer) into the question. (Questions should stand alone and be complete.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found out why the lat lng data was that strange in this case. For importing the data with osm2pgsql in slime node the additional table named planet_osm_nodes is getting generated and that was the one I used. Without the additional parameter `-l` in the import statement the coordinates are getting projected in the Sperical Mercator projection EPSG:3857. So this issue doesn't come up with using this paramter. Afterwards the values are still integers and thats pretty unuseful, but a cast to floor and everything is fine.
Hope someone who has the same issue finds this answer.

Comment: Have to wait another 21 hours. Just be patient!

Comment: To add further, `-l` is [also documented as `--latlong`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md#projection-options)

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of knowing the error messages are you getting, here's my take on some initial improvements -- I'm new to this too.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable,node
WHERE node.tags @> ARRAY['subway', 'station', 'uic_ref']
  and ST_DWithin(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(mylon, mylat),3857), radius)
```

Comment: yeaI forgot the from, but that wasn't the issue. 
So the crucial point in my quesion is how I can transform the input data, that's common lng, lat degrees to compare it with the geom inside, because the lng, lat that are used in the database are in a very different format and I think that's something to do with the SRID, but I hardly know anything about this.

Comment: so the usual lng = 16.547 and lat=48.24 is in this format lat:614161876 and lng:182462380 and thats pretty awkward

Comment: Maybe it's EPSG:3857 -- spheroidal mercator in meters?  Modified answer to reflect that one.

Comment: No luck with 3857 :-(